# I have a DataFrame with multiple rows. Is there any way in which they can be combined to form one string?

Tags: pandas, dataset, rows

```
   
        name
    0    md tim
    1    sd mit
    2    jk jason
    3    gk jasim
    4    dr sible
    5    sm amir

Expected output: 


          name
    0    md mit
    1    sd tim
    2    jk jasim
    3    gk jason
    4    dr amir
    5    sm sible
```

Comment: Your expected output is not a single string. It is another DataFrame with replaced second word in each pair of rows. Make up your mind what change to your data you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want what you wrote in the **title** of this post, you can run:

```
' '.join(df.reset_index().values.astype(str).reshape(1, -1).tolist()[0])
```

The result is just a single string, with index values and names, separated
with a single space.

Of course, this solution gives different result than your expected result, but,
just as you wrote in the title, it is a single string.

## Edit

To get your expected result (a DataFrame with second word interchanged
within each pair of rows):

1. Define a function:

   ```
   def exchg(grp):
       tbl = grp.str.split(' ').tolist()
       tbl[0][1], tbl[1][1] = tbl[1][1], tbl[0][1]
       return pd.Series(map(lambda row: ' '.join(row), tbl), index=grp.index)
   ```
2. Then group your DataFrame (actually only *name* column) into pairs
   and transform each pair, using the above function:

   ```
   df.name.groupby(np.arange(len(df.index)) // 2).transform(exchg)
   ```

Comment: I want to as like as I have shown in the figure.please help me

Comment: brother, I need another help... I want to generate random name using a dataset , how can I do this? not like my first work that comparing two rows

Comment: This is rather material for **another** question. It is a bad habit to place one question and gradually extend it by other issues.